# php 'include' gives errors in css

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a website in php. I have a `navigation.php` page, a `design.php` page and a `footer.php` page. All the three pages have their own internal CSS.  I am adding all the three pages in `index.php` using include command. 
Something like this:

**index.php** :

```
<?php
include 'navigation.php';
include 'design.php';
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

But as some of the html elements in navigation.php and footer.php are identical like unordered lists `ul` or `li`  but their CSS is different in both the files. But when I open `index.php` page some of the parts of `footer.php` get messed up due to different CSS for same html elements in `navigation.php`. But when I open them separately no problem is there.

Pages are like this:

**navigation.php:**

```
<style>
....css...
</style>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Sign Up</li>
<li>Log In</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

**footer.php**

```
<style>
...css...
</style>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Privacy Policy</li>
<li>Report Bug</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

This is just sample code. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are all those php file you mention in same folder ??

Comment: ya all are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

I dnt know what is inside your design.php but for index.php try this

```
  <?php include_once( 'header.php');?>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <title>index.php</title>
       </head>

         <body>
           ..something.... 
         </body>
       <?php include_once('footer.php');?> 
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are redefining the same styles in your various php files. Try to set a class on the ul element and define your styles for ul, e.g. likle this

header.php

```
<style>
.header {
color: red;
}
</style>
<ul class="header">
<li>blabla</li>
<li>bla</li>
</ul>
```

footer.php

```
<style>
.footer {
color: blue;
}
</style>
<ul class="footer">
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ul>
```

You should also remove the `<body>` tags from the includes. You can have only one body tag in the html page.

Comment: its not possible for me to set a class for each element all over again because there's a lot of code like seriously a lot. Can you suggest some other way with which one page's css does not affect other's while using include.

Comment: You only need to set the class on a parent object, like I did with UL. The style will then apply to all children as well. No need to set the class to all children. Without any selector styles repeated in the same html page will overwrite each other. You can add the same class selector to different styles. See here for examples http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp